# MySQL - Find substring and select only 255 charcaters from the whole sentence

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to select a 255 characters max from a text and returns only the substring containing the matched words a user is looking for or the first one.

This is a script for a search engine in my site where results preview only posts containing  the set of words the user is searching.

```
Here is an example for a preview:

  A user type in search box "manufacturing companies"

 ...visited the campus to announce the creation of a new public-private **Manufacturing** Innovation Institute that will soon take up residence at NC State. Eighteen **companies** headquartered in North Carolina will partner...

In case there are more coincidences, select only the substring that contains more words matched.

How can I accomplish this within a query?
```

Thanks.

Comment: SQL (and even regular expressions) are not suited for this task, particularly the part about getting the substring with 255 characters that has the most matches.

Comment: `select REGEXP_REPLACE(<params>) from <table> where REGEXP_LIKE(<params>)` is supported by multiple SQL DBs, for MySql - You'll need a plugin/module: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql, once You install those and read the manuals - show some effort of trying to acheive it on Your own (as required by StackOverflow rules to avoid down-votes)